# Error: Invalid literal for int() with base 2: ' '

Tags: python, binary, int

I am using huge binary numbers, they come with 1024 digits and sometimes this code works well, but sometimes not. I think that this is very strange.
This is the code that I'm using to transform binary into decimal

```
def binToDec(d):
    z1 = (Random binary number) 
    z = z1[:d]
    n = int(z,2)
    num=float(n)
    return num
```

when the code fail they write to me

```
n = int(z,2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: ''
```

somebody can help?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a number that this fails on?

Comment: @jordanm (and Vitor) `int('',2)` (or any other base), raises the value error.  I edited to make error message clearer.

Comment: Is `d` ever `0`? Can `z1` be an empty string?

Comment: Please write a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error. As it stands, we can't see how you generate `d` or `z1`. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Thanks for all comments and answers. Its helps a lot.
The problem occur because have no number to transform to binary, the error message say this here, but i do not  understanded it before:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '' <- ( no number )

Just for an example when the code have failure with a not binary number occur that message:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '1328409374ddsdj' <- (not a binary number)

Answer (score 0):

`int('',2)`, or any other base, raises ValueError.  You omitted the rest of the stack trace (bad idea), but there must be a `bintoDec(0)` call, possibly with the `0` being the value of some other variable.